# Getting data out of a <TD> Element using Python

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping

I am writing an agent for plex and I am scraping the following html table
I am rather new to python and web scraping in general

I am trying to get to the data XXXXXXXXXX

1. THE DATA

```
<table class="d">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="ch">title</th>
            <th class="ch">released</th>
            <th class="ch">company</th>
            <th class="ch">type</th>
            <th class="ch">rating</th>
            <th class="ch">category</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cd" valign="top">
              <a href="/V/6/58996.html">XXXXXXXXXX</a>
            </td>
            <td class="cd">2015</td>
            <td class="cd">My Films</td>
            <td class="cd">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="cd">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="cd">General Hardcore</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

2. THE CODE

This is a segment of the code I am using :

```
    myTable = HTML.ElementFromURL(searchQuery, sleep=REQUEST_DELAY).xpath('//table[contains(@class,"d")]/tr')
    self.log('SEARCH:: My Table: %s', myTable)

    # This logs the following
    #2019-12-26 00:26:49,329 (17a4) :  INFO (logkit:16) - GEVI - SEARCH:: My Table: [<Element tr at 0x5225c30>, <Element tr at 0x5225c00>]


    for myRow in myTable:
        siteTitle = title[0]
        self.log('SEARCH:: Site Title: %s', siteTitle)

        siteTitle = title[0].text_content().strip()
        self.log('SEARCH:: Site Title: %s', siteTitle)

        # This logs the following for <tr>/<th> - ROW 1
        # 2019-12-26 00:26:49,335 (17a4) :  INFO (logkit:16) - GEVI - SEARCH:: Site Title: <Element th at 0x5225180>
        # 2019-12-26 00:26:49,342 (17a4) :  INFO (logkit:16) - GEVI - SEARCH:: Site Title: title

        # This logs the following for <tr>/<th> - ROW 2
        # 2019-12-26 00:26:49,362 (17a4) :  INFO (logkit:16) - GEVI - SEARCH:: Site Title: <Element td at 0x52256f0>
        # 2019-12-26 00:26:49,369 (17a4) :  INFO (logkit:16) - GEVI - SEARCH:: Site Title:                              #### this is my issue... should be XXXXXXXXXX


        # I can get the href using the following code
        siteURL = myRow.xpath('.//td/a')[0].get('href')
```

3. THE QUESTIONS

A. How do I get the value 'XXXXXXXXXX', I tried using xPath but it picked up data from another table on the same page
B. Is There a better way of getting the href attribute?

4. OTHER

The python libraries I am using are
import datetime, linecache, platform, os, re, string, sys, urllib

I can not use beautifulsoup as this is an agent for plex and therefore i am assuming that whoever wanted to use this agent would have to install beautifulsoup.
so that is a no go

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html = '''<table class="d">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="ch">title</th>
            <th class="ch">released</th>
            <th class="ch">company</th>
            <th class="ch">type</th>
            <th class="ch">rating</th>
            <th class="ch">category</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cd" valign="top">
              <a href="/V/6/58996.html">XXXXXXXXXX</a>
            </td>
            <td class="cd">2015</td>
            <td class="cd">My Films</td>
            <td class="cd">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="cd">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="cd">General Hardcore</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
table = doc.getElement('table','d') # doc.getElement(tag='table',attr='class',value='d')
trs = table.trs.contains('<a ') # table.getElementsByTag('tr').contains('<a ')
for tr in trs:
  a = tr.a
  print (a) 
  print (a.text) # XXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: I can not use scrappy as it leaves me in the same bind as beautiful soup.. Is there a way to do it in plain xpath or plain standard python using the libraries that come as standard with python??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to do with XPath. By the way, this is not scrappy, but it can extract almost everything.

Comment: As I have mentioned, I can only use the standard libraries that ship out with python. So srappy, beautifulsoup, simplifieddoc are just not an option. But thank you so much for taking the time to answer and help

Comment: It's ok. You can use regex to do this. SimplifiedDoc library is implemented by regex.